# React Use Context : Cannot destructure property 'token' of '(0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

i'm trying to save token and user info in react context , i have them in my cookies , i want also to check if the user have them (after getting them from cookies and setting them into states) you can pass to routes.
I'm getting this error while i go to routes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4ncu.png)

this is my authProvider.js

```
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null);
  const [cookies] = useCookies(["userToken", "userInfo"]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(cookies.userInfo);
    console.log(cookies.userToken);
    setToken(cookies.userToken);
    setUserInfo(cookies.userInfo);
  }, [cookies]); 

  
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        token,
        userInfo,
        setToken,
        setUserInfo,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

and this is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import {AuthProvider} from './context/authProvider';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AuthProvider>
         <App />
      </AuthProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

And in my App.js i have imported AppRoutes.js

this is my AppRoutes.js

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import Login from "./Login/Login";
// import Home from "./Home/Home"
import Register from "./Register/Register";
// import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard/Dashboard";
import Tasks from "./Tasks/Tasks";
import Schedule from "./Schedule/Schedule";
import PomodoroPage from "./Pomodoro/PomodoroPage";
import Goals from "./Goals/Goals";
import Journals from "./Journals/Journals";
import AppLayout from "../Components/AppLayout/AppLayout";
import Logout from "./Logout/Logout";
import { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";
import PrivateRoutes from "./PrivateRoutes/PrivateRoutes";
function AppRoutes() {

  return (
    <div className="appRoutes">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
        <Route path="/logout" element={<Logout />} />
        <Route path="/app" element={<AppLayout />}>
          <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path="tasks" element={<Tasks />} />
          <Route path="schedule" element={<Schedule />} />
          <Route path="pomodoro" element={<PomodoroPage />} />
          <Route path="goals" element={<Goals />} />
          <Route path="journals" element={<Journals />} />
        </Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
      <Toaster />
    </div>
  );
}

export default AppRoutes;
```

and finally this is my PrivateRoutes.jsx

```
import { Outlet, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import {AuthProvider} from "../../context/authProvider";

const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { token, userInfo } = useContext(AuthProvider);
  
  console.log(token);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token || !userInfo) {
      navigate('/login');
    }
  }, [token, userInfo, navigate]);
  
  return <Outlet />;
}
export default PrivateRoutes
```

Answer (score 0):

In `PrivateRoutes.jsx`, you are importing the wrong variable for context. You should import `AuthContext` and pass it to `useContext`. Hopefully that should fix it.

Make these changes in `PrivateRoutes.jsx`:

```
import {AuthContext} from "../../context/authProvider";

// rest of code...
  const { token, userInfo } = useContext(AuthContext);
```

Comment: yes, it works for me, but still in my privateRoutes.jsx getting the stored state value as a null and navigating me to login.
Maybe setting the value in useEffect in the Provider needs time to be set in the context because , it will return null then it will return their value, that's why it navigate me to login page , so is there any solution to this issue?

Comment: Updating a state is asynchronous and takes time to be done. One way is to make a new loading state which is by default true. Once the states are set, along the setToken and setUserInfo call, you can set this loading state to false and pass it in your context provider. Then in PrivateRoutes you can set this loading state as useEffect dependency and add a condition inside useEffect to check if loading is false then you can check cookies existence and navigate